# C# ConcurrentDictionary usage inconsistent accessibility?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, foreach, .net-4.5, concurrentdictionary

I'm following along with a tutorial to build a chat client and server, right now I've got the following error:

```
Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<string,ChattingServer.ConnectedClient>' is less accessible than field 'ChattingServer.ChattingService._connectedClients' c:\Users\KOEMXE\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ChatApplication\ChattingServer\ChattingService.cs 17  62  ChattingServer
```

Here's the class file where the relevant issue lies (ChattingService.cs):

```
using ChattingInterfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace ChattingServer
{
    [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class ChattingService : IChattingService
    {
        //private ConnectedClient _connectedClients;

        public ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConnectedClient> _connectedClients = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConnectedClient>();

        public int Login(string userName)
        {
            //is anyone else logged in with my name?
            foreach (var client in _connectedClients)
            {
                if(client.Key.ToLower() == userName.ToLower())
                {
                    //if yes
                    return 1;
                }
            }

            var establishedUserConnection = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClient>();

            ConnectedClient newClient = new ConnectedClient();
            newClient.connection = establishedUserConnection;
            newClient.UserName = userName;



            _connectedClients.TryAdd(userName, newClient);

            return 0;
        }


        public void SendMessageToALL(string message, string userName)
        {
            foreach (var client in _connectedClients)
            {
                if (client.Key.ToLower() != userName.ToLower())
                {
                    client.Value.connection.GetMessage(message, userName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to declare the type in the ConcurrentDictionary object elsewhere? What's the issue? Thanks!

Comment: I would guess that ChattingServer.ConnectedClient is not public.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ChattingService` is public, and its `_connectedClients` member is public. But the type of `_connectedClients` involves `ChattingServer.ConnectedClient`, which is not public.

Imagine you were to reference your `ChattingServer` assembly from another project and then write code like this:

```
using ChattingServer;
...
ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConnectedClient> dict = myChattingService._connectedClients;
```

The accessibility of your `ChattingService` type and its `_connectedClients` field allow you to access that field, but the type `ConnectedClient` isn't public, so you have access to a field whose type should be hidden, according to the accessibility modifiers you have placed on the types and members in the `ChattingServer` assembly. This is why you are getting the build error: the accessibility modifiers on your types and members in the `ChattingServer` assembly contradict each other.

If you, for example, make `ChattingServer.ConnectedClient` public, or make `_connectedClients` private, that will fix the problem.

Comment: *hands on face* You guys are absolutely right, I missed that detail. Works fine now. Thanks.